# Cordova call plugin error

Tags: android, cordova

First i was trying to do this without any plugin. I had sanitized tel: in the code. `<a href="tel:0038098754215">`, which was working from webpage but not from mobile android.
Then i tried to add this plugin [Call Number](https://github.com/Rohfosho/CordovaCallNumberPlugin) which was added successfully but the code which i was running

```
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('testing');
    window.plugins.CallNumber.callNumber(function(res){
        console.log('res');
        console.log(res);
    }, function(err){
        console.log('err');
        console.log(err);
    }, '00380680576169', true);
},10000);
```

Had as result from browser

```
testing
err
Missing Command Error
null
```

and from mobile:

```
testing
null
```

And inside config.xml i am adding

```
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />
```

Comment: Did you add your code inside the "DeviceReady" function? Besides, I don't think you can test this plugin using the browser, but on the device only. I can't understand the mobile log you posted

Comment: This is what i see from mobile in terminal.
DeviceReady is this need? i am doing 10 second delay. Mobile looks ready at the point.

Comment: You were correct, added code inside deviceready and all worked out.

Comment: Ok @Gonchar I changed my comment as an answer so you can accept it

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code in config.xml

```
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />
```

Comment: Sorry, i miss to tell that i am adding this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your code inside the "DeviceReady" function? Besides, I don't think you can test this plugin using the browser, but on the device only.